# Optimal config for VM host

Tags: linux, performance, virtualization

I'm facing a big issue when I start my windows virtual machine. I noticed that there are a heavy disk usage, and in consequence the host desktop os is freezing and I'm not able to get back "commands".

Host OS: debian 7.2

Here is my Harware config (Asus k55vd):

i7 2nd Gen (8 threads), 8 Gb ram
750 Disk

The VM config (running windows 7):

1 Processors (2threads), 2 Gb Ram.

Recently I switched to `deadline` IO Scheduler, it seems a little bit more fast (I'm now able to execute more than 1 application on the VM)

Maybe it's due to my HW, on my old laptop (HP, Core2Duo, 3Gb Ram) every thing was fine I don't know why this is not working well on my new laptop.

Is there any other configuration that I can do to my host OS to gain more performance ?

Thank you.

**[EDIT] Added some details**

Comment: What virtualisation solution are you using ? KVM ? Virtualbox ?

Comment: Ye, we need to know more information than this to help you out... what Hypervisor are you using, KVM, Virtual Box, VMPlayer, Hyper-V? What disk set up are you using, split or single, thin or fat? What Host OS are you using and also what Guest OS?

EDIT - Just noticed that the tag linux and the bit about deadline, I dont know much about linux VM's. Will leave for the *nix bods... :)

Comment: I'm using VMWare hypervisor with debian as Host OS. didn't get your question about the disk